# AWS S3 PhPdolphin integration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So my goal was it to implement Amazon S3 image uploads to the PhPDolphin script, unfortunately I've run into a few Issues, if I add the code in the script just doesn't load and since the script doesn't have an error log I'm clueless as to what went wrong, for licensing reasons I'm unable to publish the entire script here but I will post a snipped of the affected area.

/includes/classes.php [Default (Just a small snippet of the 4000 lines of code within this file)]

```
function validateMessage($message, $image, $type, $value, $privacy) {
    // If message is longer than admitted
    if(strlen($message) > $this->message_length) {
        $error = array('message_too_long', $this->message_length);
    }
    // Define the switch variable
    $x = 0;
    if($image['name'][0]) {
        // Set the variable value to 1 if at least one image name exists
        $x = 1;
    }
    if($x == 1) {
        // If the user selects more images than allowed
        if(count($image['name']) > $this->max_images) {
            $error = array('too_many_images', count($image['name']), $this->max_images);
        } else {
            // Define the array which holds the value names
            $value = array();
            $tmp_value = array();
            foreach($image['error'] as $key => $err) {
                $allowedExt = explode(',', $this->image_format);
                $ext = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(!empty($image['size'][$key]) && $image['size'][$key] > $this->max_size) {
                    $error = array('file_too_big', fsize($this->max_size), $image['name'][$key]); // Error Code #004
                    break;
                } elseif(!empty($ext) && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowedExt)) {
                    $error = array('format_not_exist', $this->image_format, $image['name'][$key]); // Error Code #005
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(isset($image['name'][$key]) && $image['name'][$key] !== '' && $image['size'][$key] > 0) {
                        $rand = mt_rand();
                        $tmp_name = $image['tmp_name'][$key];
                        $name = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        $fullname = $image['name'][$key];
                        $size = $image['size'][$key];
                        $ext = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        // $finalName = str_replace(',', '', $rand.'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($name).'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($ext));
                        $finalName = mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($ext);

                        // Define the type for picture
                        $type = 'picture';

                        // Store the values into arrays
                        $tmp_value[] = $tmp_name;
                        $value[] = $finalName;

                        // Fix the image orientation if possible
                        imageOrientation($tmp_name);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(empty($error)) {
                foreach($value as $key => $finalName) {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_value[$key], '../uploads/media/'.$finalName);
                }
            }
            // Implode the values
            $value = implode(',', $value);
        }
```

And then my edited version that is supposed to upload the images automatically to Amazon S3.

/includes/classes.php [edited] (the s3 code is on the far bottom of the snippet)

```
function validateMessage($message, $image, $type, $value, $privacy) {
    // If message is longer than admitted
    if(strlen($message) > $this->message_length) {
        $error = array('message_too_long', $this->message_length);
    }
    // Define the switch variable
    $x = 0;
    if($image['name'][0]) {
        // Set the variable value to 1 if at least one image name exists
        $x = 1;
    }
    if($x == 1) {
        // If the user selects more images than allowed
        if(count($image['name']) > $this->max_images) {
            $error = array('too_many_images', count($image['name']), $this->max_images);
        } else {
            // Define the array which holds the value names
            $value = array();
            $tmp_value = array();
            foreach($image['error'] as $key => $err) {
                $allowedExt = explode(',', $this->image_format);
                $ext = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(!empty($image['size'][$key]) && $image['size'][$key] > $this->max_size) {
                    $error = array('file_too_big', fsize($this->max_size), $image['name'][$key]); // Error Code #004
                    break;
                } elseif(!empty($ext) && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowedExt)) {
                    $error = array('format_not_exist', $this->image_format, $image['name'][$key]); // Error Code #005
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(isset($image['name'][$key]) && $image['name'][$key] !== '' && $image['size'][$key] > 0) {
                        $rand = mt_rand();
                        $tmp_name = $image['tmp_name'][$key];
                        $name = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        $fullname = $image['name'][$key];
                        $size = $image['size'][$key];
                        $ext = pathinfo($image['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        // $finalName = str_replace(',', '', $rand.'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($name).'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($ext));
                        $finalName = mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'.'.$this->db->real_escape_string($ext);

                        // Define the type for picture
                        $type = 'picture';

                        // Store the values into arrays
                        $tmp_value[] = $tmp_name;
                        $value[] = $finalName;

                        // Fix the image orientation if possible
                        imageOrientation($tmp_name);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(empty($error)) {


                foreach($value as $key => $finalName) {
                if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

                //AWS access info
                if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'myaccesskey');
                if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'mysecretkey');


                //instantiate the class
                $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
                    S3::outObject(
                    '$tmp_value[$key]',
                    'zepstrca',
                    '.$finalName);',
                    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ
                    array(),
                    array(),
                    S3::STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD
                    );

            }
            // Implode the values
            $value = implode(',', $value);
        }
```

And yes I did add my own access and secret key :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated and will be credited!

Links to the products and API used in this:

[[PhPDolphin]](http://phpdolphin.com) [[S3.php API on Github]](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class)

Comment: are you sure your using the correct function to upload something.... i also have a AWS bucket and a simular php library to upload files.... i use the following function $s3->putObjectFile('folderOnMyServer/picture.jpg', $bucketName, 'someFolder/picture.jpg')

Comment: do you use the same S3 PhP library?

Comment: i dont think so but normally they are all pretty much the same.... i got mine from: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

Comment: i think yout outObject is equal to putObject in my library but then your storing a object.... i dont know if your goal is to store your picture as a object or as a file (jpg or whatever).... also what if you put some error_log("log something") in your code to see where it starts to fail.... maybe it doesnt execute the function at all????

Comment: yeah, I want to store the picture on s3 that the user chooses to upload

Comment: yes but i mean.... as a file or as a object?... anyway start with putting some error_log("stuff"); into your code so you can see if the function is actually executed since you dont get any clear error message back.... also check if you your S3 library has something like "outObjectFile"

Comment: the script in general doesn't load up, when I request the site it doesn't show anything.

Comment: oke.... how about creating a new empty php file where you do a simple hardcoded upload of a test picture.... if it still doesnt work and you think the s3 library doesnt work at all you could also try the link i send earlier, that library will work for sure.... im using it for a while now

Comment: I could just jump streight to your library or? Could you tell me how I could implement it on this code (the original snippet)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use the library i am using, i hope it will fix  your problems (make sure the folder on the bucket actually exists otherwise just upload something to the root of the bucket)

```
require_once 'S3.php'; 
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putObjectFile('/folderOnServer/picture.jpg', awsBucket, '/folderOnBucket/newName.jpg');
```

Comment: so I added the code but as soon as I paste in my credentials into the (awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey); field the script crashes again.

Comment: oke... so if it only crashes WITH the s3 code and works fine without.... then maybe you can do these 3 things for debugging porposes.....can you check the following.... first: // Check for CURL
if (!extension_loaded('curl') && !@dl(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'so' ? 'curl.so' : 'php_curl.dll'))
 exit("\nERROR: CURL extension not loaded\n\n"); .... also do you have the tool "S3 browser" here you can double check if you can connect with your accesskey and secret.... and very last thing... whats your current PHP version?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm running on the latest version of PHP. I also checked, my credentials are correct. I also have CURL installed. Do I paste the credentials in the S3.php file or in to the actual file I'm using at the moment?

Comment: you should be able to use the code as pasted above, i defined my key and secret in 1 place, you can also just replace it with some strings, so no need to put them into the S3.php , just include the file and instantiate it and use the putObjectFile (if you want to dump a jpg or whatever) or putObject (if you want to make use objects, i never it myself though)....... so this still means your script keeps crashing right? pretty sure this is not a AWS problem, any change to just use run the AWS code seperate to double confirm the AWS if fine?

Comment: The script crashes as soon as I paste in my credentials into $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

Comment: any online link where the crash is visable to see, im getting very very very curious why php 5.5 or 5.6 would "crash" on something like this and not show any error message, also maybe you can show your PHP INFO printed out.